# Implementing search on list of strings

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I'm implementing a search on a list of strings and the search is not doing what I want so if someone could help me.

[image: This is the types of string where I search the written word]

[image: this is what happend when i search for me]
This is the code I use:

```
onSearchTextChanged(String text) {
    searchResults1.clear();
    searchResults2.clear();

    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }
    final textToLowerCase = text.toLowerCase();

    this.widget.songs.forEach((s) {
      if (s.title.toLowerCase().contains(textToLowerCase))
        searchResults2.add(s);
    });

    this.widget.artists.forEach((a) {
      if (a.name.toLowerCase().contains(textToLowerCase)) searchResults1.add(a);
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
```

```
TextField(
                          onSubmitted: (value) {
                            showH = false;
                            this.controller.text == ''
                                ? null
                                : insertHistory(this.controller.text);
                          },
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              showH = true;
                            });
                          },
                          controller: controller,
                          onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                          style: TextStyle(height: 1.7),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(bottom: maxHeight * 0.0175),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                size: 15,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                controller.clear();
                                onSearchTextChanged('');
                              },
                            ),
                            hintText: "Search tracks, artists",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                        ),
```

but it gives me strange results if let's say I search for mere it will not find anything, but there are at least 15 strings with that word in the list.
Thanks for help, if something needed i can provide just tell me.

Comment: From the app screenshot in the question, it looks like it is working fine. I don't see the problem. What is it?

Comment: when I let's say search for "mere" it should show that 4 first songs. but it shows nothing, so I think the problem is contains()...

Comment: But in the screenshot it is showing the songs list correctly. You have typed "me" and all the song titles containing "me" are there in the list below.

Comment: But if I write "mer" it will show nothing and I can't get it why.

Comment: Strange. Where have you called this method `onSearchTextChanged` ? On the `TextField`'s `onChanged` callback, right?

Comment: updated code you can get a look what I'm doing in TextField

Comment: Looks perfect. Can't think of a reason why this must be happening. I even tried out a minimal demo on dartpad and it works fine on there.

Comment: somehow if I type 2 letters it finds something, but if I type 3 letters there is a small chance it will show something... I tried to remove whitespace from string but nothing happened. Maybe I'm missing something but I can't see what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in SilverList I give the wrong "childCount: searchResults1.length", the right way is "childCount: searchResults2.length".. Thanks to all you guys who tried to help me.

Comment: lol a small typo and we were looking for the bug all over the code :D

Comment: yeah but thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to normalize your search (in your example with lowercase) you need to normalize *both* your search term *and* the strings you search:

```
s.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())
```

Ideally, you would do this *once*

```
final textToLowerCase = text.toLowerCase();
```

and then use *that*:

```
s.title.toLowerCase().contains(textToLowerCase)
```

In addition to that, your method is not `async` and you should call `setState` only *once* when you are done setting state. So your method should look like this:

```
onSearchTextChanged(String text) {
    searchResults1.clear();
    searchResults2.clear();

    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    final textToLowerCase = text.toLowerCase();

    this.widget.songs.forEach((s) {
      if (s.title.toLowerCase().contains(textToLowerCase)) searchResults2.add(s);
    });

    this.widget.artists.forEach((a) {
      if (a.name.toLowerCase().contains(textToLowerCase)) searchResults1.add(a);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: I edited my question you can see what I get when I search for me but if I write "mer" it will not find anything, any idea?

Comment: Did you already incorporate the changes I suggested?

Comment: yes, you can see it the question is edited

Comment: Well, you'll have to debug it then.